# Rails: Proc in routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm reading The Rails 3 Way and I don't understand why there's a proc in the routes. I still have a hard time grasping the use of proc/lambda and how they are used.

How is this:

```
match 'records/:id' => "records#protected",
  :constraints => proc {|req| req.params[:id].to_i < 100 }
```

different from:

```
match 'records/:id' => "records#protected",
  :constraints => params[:id].to_i < 100
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you're more familiar with JavaScript? Procs are similar to anonymous functions. The first version of your code is roughly equivalent to:

```
{ constraints: function(req) { return req.params["id"] < 100 }}
```

That is, `constraints` is being set to a block of code which can be evaluated at a later time.

The second version would be like writing

```
{ constraints: return req.params["id"] < 100 }
```

which is to say, a syntax error, and logically broken as it tries to evaluate `return req.params["id"] < 100` immediately as the code is interpreted, before `req` has even been defined.

This is the primary difference between your two versions, and why the `proc` is important: You need to pass the code into the route so it can be evaluated later when routing occurs.

Comment: so procs are always called after everything else is called?

Comment: what exactly is passed into proc? and does it vary in different situations?

Comment: Yes. Whatever code invokes the proc is free to pass anything into it. Procs are, in essence, just functions stored in variables. When you execute the function, you can pass anything you could normally pass into a function.

Comment: Err, sorry, no to your first comment, yes to your second comment. Procs are called whenever they're called. Your routing file is just plain-old Ruby code. You're calling a function (`match`) and passing to it a Hash, containing the key `:condition` which has a matching value, which is a `Proc`. Internally, in the implementation you don't have to care about, Rails is storing your routes in such a way that, when routing happens, it can execute whatever Proc is attached to the route's `condition` property.

Answer (score 0):

By providing a Proc to the route you are able to dynamically constrain the route matching. It allows you to execute arbitrary code that can determine whether or not the route should match.

In your example, you only want that route to match for requests that pass an `id` that is less that 100. There really isn't a better way to express that constraint - a Proc is really the best choice.